# Calculate Weekly totals and should appear immediately after the corresponding week's data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a data like below

| contact_date | count | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06/01/2023 | 230 | 0 |
| 06/02/2023 | 100 | 0 |
| 06/03/2023 | 200 | 0 |
| 06/04/2023 | 250 | 0 |
| 06/05/2023 | 120 | 0 |
| 06/06/2023 | 120 | 0 |
| 06/07/2023 | 200 | 0 |
| 06/08/2023 | 2230 | 0 |
| 06/09/2023 | 2310 | 0 |
| 06/10/2023 | 30 | 0 |
| 06/11/2023 | 300 | 0 |
| 06/12/2023 | 100 | 0 |
| 06/13/2023 | 120 | 0 |
| 06/14/2023 | 790 | 0 |
| 06/15/2023 | 900 | 0 |

and I want to calculate the weekly totals for the count and values and display the weekly total right after week. Weeks start Sunday and ends on Saturday. technically it should look like below

| contact_date | count | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06/01/2023 | 230 | 0 |
| 06/02/2023 | 100 | 0 |
| 06/03/2023 | 200 | 0 |
| Weektot | 530 | 0 |
| 06/04/2023 | 250 | 0 |
| 06/05/2023 | 120 | 0 |
| 06/06/2023 | 120 | 0 |
| 06/07/2023 | 200 | 0 |
| 06/08/2023 | 2230 | 0 |
| 06/09/2023 | 2310 | 0 |
| Weektot | 5260 | 0 |
| 06/10/2023 | 30 | 0 |
| 06/11/2023 | 300 | 0 |
| 06/12/2023 | 100 | 0 |
| 06/13/2023 | 120 | 0 |
| 06/14/2023 | 790 | 0 |
| 06/15/2023 | 900 | 0 |
| Weektot | value | 0 |

Here is the code I have written, I was able to calculate at the weekly level but I am not able to order it correctly. All the week data is appending at the end of the result

```
WITH WeeklyData AS (
    SELECT
        contact_date,
        count,
        values,
        DATEPART(WEEK, contact_date) AS week_number
    FROM table
)

SELECT
    contact_date,
    count,
    values
FROM WeeklyData
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Week',
    SUM(count),
    SUM(values)
FROM WeeklyData
GROUP BY week_number
ORDER BY contact_date;
```

Comment: Have a look at `GROUPING SETS`; I *think* that was available in the now completely unsupported (for 4 years) SQL Server 2008.